# upload generated image to server

Tags: javascript, image, svg, base64

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/amcharts/Hg6dg/) shows a map created with the [ammap](http://www.ammap.com/) library. This library creates the map using SVG. I want to use this map in a PDF/XLS report that's generated on the server-side, so the first step (I think) is to convert it into an image format that can be embedded in PDF/XLS documents.

If you click the Export button the SVG is converted to a base64-encoded PNG and added to the DOM. In other words, the following element is added to the DOM (base64 encoding abbreviated)

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgAAAGQCAYAAAByNR6YAAAgAElEQVR4nOydd3hU55n26aJJAoHoiN6r6WDAuFFscMXdxhgbG2PADWOK4ySbuok32V3vJrGdsmmbOP6SdbLxRqOu6XPOgCRUZ0aj3jUz0vQz9f7+ONJIozqjM">
```

However, rather than appending the PNG to the DOM, what I really want to do is upload the image to the server, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could send your png image to the server in a post request. With luck you could even get the .pdf result in that request. Check the instructions on how to retrieve the binary data for your image: [Get image data in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript) (Just noticed that you already have the base64 data, so you are already half the way towards the solution)